# Ошибка при использовании "Яндекс Карт"

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

использую карты вторую неделю, до сегодняшнего дня всё было нормально, а сегодня карта перестала нормально функционировать. При вводе в строку поиска адреса оно выводит подсказки по похожим адресам, но при выборе конкретного адреса выдаёт ошибку "Сервер не смог обработать запрос", не добавляет метку и не отображает этот адрес на карте.

[image: До выбора нужного адреса]

А после того, как я выбираю правильный адрес происходит следующее:[image: После выбора нужного адреса]

Поиск ничего внятного не дал, в чём может быть проблема?

P.S. Думал количество запросов, но 25.000 точно не было. На странице у меня два экземпляра карты, но до сегодняшнего дня работало, не думаю, что из-за этого.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на сайт или jsfiddle где можно увидеть проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, только работало нормально намного меньше времени.
У меня была такая особенность: скрипт-файл для инициализации карт, загружался не по ссылке на yandex, а локально я его себе сохранил и соответственно загружал так же на саму страницу.
Изменив способ загрузки на страницу, по ссылке на yandex, всплыла немного другая проблема, что сам скрипт уже может загружаться намного дольше, в следствии чего, у меня в js-коде те же методы слишком рано пытались даже подписаться на событие ready у карт (cannot read property ready of null). Пришлось добавить небольшую задержку (setTimeout) для вызова методов подписки на это событие.