# Поиск адреса или объекта на карте, вставленной в сайт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

На сайт вставлена карта Яндекса. На любой запрос, в т.ч. и из выпадающего меню,  в строке с подсказкой "адрес или объект" выдаёт "сервер не смог обработать запрос". Требуется ли какая-либо доработка "Яндекс карт" или всё делается на стороне сайта.
Карта вставлена сдесь: http://zakolki-nsk.ru/contact-us . Я не программист. Просто программисты говорят, что надо править яндекс-карты, а на сайте они всё правильно сделали. В чём я сомневаюсь, отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: Показывайте код

Comment: [Ошибка при использовании "Яндекс Карт"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808800/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82)

Answer (score 0):

Вызов API Яндекс.Карт требует указания полученного в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/services/) api-ключа "**JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер**".

В вашем случае этот ключ не указан. Получите ключ и пропишите его в вызов API согласно [инструкции](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load.html).

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```